# How to insert module into ARM which use kernel from open embedded

Tags: openembedded

I'm trying to insert a module.ko on ARM which use a kernel customized by open embedded. I would like to know how can I achieve that. Is the insmod and modprobe commands works or should I create a recipes ?

Actually, I have ve tried the first one (insmod) but the module behave strangely.

Also, if the solution is the second option, how can I add a recipes with an external module inside open embedded ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

If you're trying to load the module "module.ko", then yes, the standard tools like insmod and modprobe are what you should be using. There's also a possibility of auto-loading the module upon boot.

If you're trying to build the external module and get it integrated into you image, then you need to look at writing a recipe for the module and adding it to your image recipe.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is integrating an external module into my image. This need indeed to write a new recipes which is pretty difficult since it is a kernel linux routing module.

Comment: Have you looked into any of the existing recipes for external modules?

As long as your external module doesn't require patching of the kernel, creating a standalone oe recipe is usually no big issue.